# Running shell scripts from Cake PHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have an application that I have written in a very MVC fashion using Cake PHP.  I now need to execute a shell script from within the application.  Does Cake PHP provide a way of executing shell scripts?  I.e. is there anything built in to do this or not?  I am using CakePHP 2.

Many thanks :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes, you can easily execute shell scripts manually from within your application.
in 2.x this is even easier than in 1.3 etc:

```
App::uses('MyShell', 'Console/Command');
$this->My = new MyShell();
$this->My->myMethod();
```

I use it to test the shells I write inside the test cases. But it would also work within the app :)

Similar with Tasks.
I use that in my TranslatePlugin to execute the ExtractTask of the core with some specific settings directly from the controller/model level.

Be aware that you might have to add/pass some manual ConsoleOutput class if you have some specific shell script.
It would be better to move your code to a Task (not a shell!) if possible.
Even better, move it inside a Lib or some other generic file you can dispatch from both your shell and your normal app code. This would be the cleanest approach on this subject.

Comment: Thanks for this! For anyone else that uses the CakePHP Queue plugin and want to test a Task, you would do this: App::uses('QueueMyTask', 'Plugin/Queue/Console/Command/Task');

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, no. Shell script are -as the name suggests- meant to be run from a shell and not from within your app.

Although, there are some pointers how you can make your app interact with your shells in deizel's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692221/cakephp-run-shell-job-from-controller).