# CakePHP 2.x non public .php script for CRON without CLI

Tags: cakephp, cron, cakephp-2.0, command-line-interface

I need PHP file with CakePHP 2.x MVC logic, which is not accessible from browser(URL).
But I cant use console/shell becouse I dont have a proper hosting (I cannot run a cake bash file)
I need this for a cronjob with PHP script (example test.php - I can run a php script, but I cannot run bash file).

Comment: this is not quite a whishlist here ("please bake me.."). what exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: @mark you dont understand me, I dont want anything to bake, I need only where I can put some code with cakePHP logic and save it as .php file and run it from cron - but not accessible via URL

Comment: Call a controller/action from outside. There are even free services to do so. Or better: upgrade your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this natively. Console commands are to run in the console. If you don't have access to console then there is no immediate way to run a cron against it. However, there is a way to force a controller/action to execute console scripts. Then what you would need to do is run a cron that fetches that controller action.

Someone has already provided sample code to do this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9000052/372875

If his aco_sync() action was in a ConsoleFuncs controller, you could fetch http://yoursite.com/console_funcs/aco_sync to run the shell script. On the machine that you want to setup your cron jobs, the script would simple do a curl to that URL and thus, execute that console script.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this correctly, you need a way to run  cron jobs on a CakePHP application where you do not have access to the application via a browser or a command line? Well, hopefully you mean you can not access it via a browser but it still lives on some type of network. Create a script that make a request to your Controller/Action then make a cronjob to that script. You might want to make use of Cake's Json or XML views. Also, consider reading up on [Creating stateless authentication system](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-stateless-authentication-systems) if you need to secure the controller/action behind a username/password.

Comment: Not exactly. I need to run script, that is not accessible via URL. Its a public web so it cannot be a controller with action, which you can trigger from browser. Problem is that my hosting doesnt allow me to run cake console shell task, becouse I have to run bash cake script. I need to execute .php script not a shell task.

Comment: And you say this is in the CakePHP MVC? I don't know how this can be possible. I might just not be understanding your question. Where does the script live? it sounds to me like if it is not an action then you might not be using CakePHP the right way.

Comment: @angel-s-moreno In cake is console/shell tasks http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html and I need exactly the same thing, but I want to run .php script not cake console program