# CLI cron job sending get request to URL but 404 for everyone else

Tags: cakephp, command-line-interface, cakephp-2.3

I would like to setup a cron job for CakePHP which sends GET request a URL in my Cake Application, (or runs a function in my controller). However, if an user visits this URL, they will just get a 404 to prevent abuse.

How can I accomplish this? Would something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692221/cakephp-run-shell-job-from-controller/9000052#9000052) work well?

Note: I am using CakePHP 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (and reasonably secure) way to do this is to check the *user agent*.  Something like this (sample assumes you're using "wget" from cron).  In the crontab, you could use this to have it run at 7 minutes after each hour:

```
    7  * * * * cd /tmp; /usr/bin/wget http://domain/controller/cron; rm cron
```

If the cron job is running on the same server as the website, you can use "localhost" instead of "domain"; otherwise, use the name of your domain (ex: "www.example.com").  Substitute the name of the controller you want your cron method in for the word "controller".  Next, in the controller's PHP:

```
public function cron() {
    if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 4) != 'wget') 
        $this->redirect('/');
    ...
```

It's only "reasonably" secure, because it's not hard to spoof the user agent.  I can't give you a good way to generate a 404 without knowing more about your app (someone else probably can, though); this will send them to your home page, which is maybe good enough.

If you want to use a different name (other than "cron"), remember to change the crontab and the PHP.

If you're not using cron to call wget to call your method, you can adapt this to whatever user agent string the method you do use generates.

If it were me, I'd probably also have it check that it's the right *time* to be called by cron (ex: within the first 10 seconds of the 7th minute of the hour).