# Cakephp 3.x. Execute custom console command from a Model

Tags: shell, command, background-process, cakephp-3.x

Thanks in advance to all who wants to help...

I'm following the [console commands](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/commands.html) guide that appears on cakephp 3.x cookbook. I have created the first example for trying to understand how it works

```html
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Cake\Console\Arguments;
use Cake\Console\Command;
use Cake\Console\ConsoleIo;

class HelloCommand extends Command
{
    public function execute(Arguments $args, ConsoleIo $io)
    {
        $io->out('Hello world.');
    }
}
```

I have saved that on src/Console, and when I execute as they said in the guide "bin/cake hello", everything is perfect, however, I want to be able to run the console command from the model. I have cheched by internet and I have tried some things but I'm not succesfull on that.

Thanks again!

Comment: According to the [manual](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/commands.html), you'll need to save it into the `src/Commands` folder, instead of the `src/Console` folder.

Comment: Thank you @Spingolini for your answer, you are right, I wrote wrong, I saved in this place ("src/Commands"), and when I execute from console, all works fine but I want to execute from model. The idea is to write a file in the background

Comment: should be the inverse: you write your logic in the model. And then you can reuse your code both in the console and in the controller.

Comment: Isn't the model only responsible for managing data, @arillia? Usually, the controller holds the business logic of the application.

Comment: yes Model is responsable to manage data, but in my case I have one model to bring data and write one excel file "xlsx". in some cases, task is slow depending of size of the data. thats why I want to execute it on background. Also it is possible to locate on a Controller for writing the file but I haven't found until now how to call custom command

Comment: This could be the right answer for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697141/8394877

Comment: Ok @Spingolini , I have checked this thread before but I wanted to learn how to use the console command for not to install innecesary things, But as I haven't found yet, let me try and I will write here the results. Thank you arilia and Spingolini for your time and your valious comments

Comment: You are looking for a way that your Model can spawn a command line task, so that it can run in the background while the browser returns an immediate response to the user?

Comment: @Greg Schmidt What you said it is correct, just the variant is: it doesn't  matter if the browser is open or not, when users push a button "download" it will launche the process and I will notify by email that file is ready for downloading

Comment: Hi guys, I took advice of @Spingolini, I installed cakephp-queue and seems so good!. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got a solution.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to say that it sounded like you needed a cron-based solution. Here's the one I've been using, in case you run into a problem with cakephp-queue and want to look at an alternative. https://github.com/trentrichardson/cakephp-scheduler